# What is between diminutive and augmentative in Russian?

Tags: морфология, суффиксы

Russian has diminutive form (уменьшительно-ласкательная форма) and augmentative form (увеличительно-усиливающая форма). For example: человечек and человечище. But how the middle, normal form is called (человек)?

Comment: I am not aware of any special term. I'd go for "neutral form" if I needed to refer to it.

Comment: And how is it called in English?

Answer (score 2):

"Middle, normal form" is called "начальная форма".

Comment: _Человека_ (oblique case) is not diminutive or augmentative yet it is also not начальная форма.

Comment: @jwalker No, it is. "начальная форма" doesn't mean that it is nominative.

Comment: What does it mean then?

Comment: @jwalker Oh... *Человека* is genitive of *Человек*. *Человек*, *Человека*, *Человеку*, *Человеком* are all in "начальная форма". *Человечек*, *Человечка*, *Человечку*, *Человечком* - "уменьшительно-ласкательная форма". *Человечище*, *Человечища*, *Человечищу*, *Человечищем* - "увеличительно-усиливающая форма"

Comment: Well, I hoped for a definition. [Here it is](http://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/2307/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's "начальная форма". And in my understanding of how form names are formed, if there was some suffix (affix, postfix, or whatever) to make this neutral form, we would have some special word for it, but there is none. It's just the form from which you start and make any other form.

Answer (score 0):

No special term is used. It's just normal form (нормальная форма), or initial form, base form of word.

Comment: No. Used. As you see.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it "Стандартная форма."